# HumanDate for easier date calculations

Tags: javascript, beginner, datetime

I need to calculate some dates like yesterday, this week/month, last three/ten days etc.

To make it a little bit easier and don't think about the `Date` weirdness all the time I created this helper:

```
var HumanDate = function() {

  var date = new Date();

  this.day = function(numOfDays) {
    if (numOfDays === undefined) {
        return date.getDate();
    }
    else {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + numOfDays);
        return this;
    }
  };

  this.month = function(month) {
    if (month === undefined) {
      return date.getMonth() + 1;
    } 
    else {
      date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + month);
      return this;
    }
  };

  this.year = function() {
    return date.getFullYear();
  };

  this.dayOfWeek = function() {
        var dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
    return dayOfWeek === 0 ? dayOfWeek + 1 : dayOfWeek;
    };

  this.beginningOfTheWeek = function() {
    return this.day(-this.dayOfWeek() + 1);
  }

  this.endOfTheWeek = function() {
    return this.day(7 - this.dayOfWeek());
  }

  this.beginningOfTheMonth = function() {
    return this.day(-this.day() + 1);
  }

  this.endOfTheMonth = function() {
    return this.day(7 - this.dayOfWeek());
  }

  this.toJSDate = function(format) {
    return date;
  }

};
```

Examples:

```
console.log('day: ' + new HumanDate().day());
console.log('month: ' + new HumanDate().month());
console.log('year: ' + new HumanDate().year());
console.log('day of week: ' + new HumanDate().dayOfWeek());

console.log('yesterday: ' + new HumanDate().day(-1).day());
console.log('next month: ' + new HumanDate().month(1).toJSDate());
console.log('last month: ' + new HumanDate().month(-1).toJSDate());
console.log('beginning of the week: ' + new HumanDate().beginningOfTheWeek().toJSDate());
console.log('end of the week: ' + new HumanDate().endOfTheWeek().toJSDate());
console.log('beginning of the month: ' + new HumanDate().beginningOfTheMonth().toJSDate());
console.log('end of the week: ' + new HumanDate().endOfTheWeek().toJSDate());
```

Output:

> ```
> day: 7
> month: 9
> year: 2016
> day of week: 3
> yesterday: 6
> next month: Fri Oct 07 2016 20:04:50 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)
> last month: Sun Aug 07 2016 20:04:50 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)
> beginning of the week: Mon Sep 05 2016 20:04:50 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)
> end of the week: Sun Sep 11 2016 20:04:50 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)
> beginning of the month: Thu Sep 01 2016 20:04:50 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)
> end of the week: Sun Sep 11 2016 20:04:50 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)
> ```

*I need it for Google Sheets scripting & calculations so I'd rather not use an external library - (at least for now)*

Comment: You pass a parameter "format" to your "toJSDate" method. But it isn't used.

Comment: @mizech oh, I forgot to remove it after I realized that the js date cannot be formatted.

Comment: No big issue. ;) But I thought I mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- I find your method naming to be really confusing. To me, if I called methods named `.day()`, `.month()`, `year()`, etc. I would be expecting methods named in this manner to behave more like a getter than a setter.

For example, this usage seems very confusing:

```
new HumanDate().day(-1).day()
```

Consider naming like `modifyDay()`, `modifyMonth()`, etc.

- You have unnecessary `else` conditions.

For example:

```
if (numOfDays === undefined) {
    return date.getDate();
}
else {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + numOfDays);
    return this;
}
```

Could more clearly be written as:

```
if (numOfDays === undefined) {
    return date.getDate();
}

date.setDate(date.getDate() + numOfDays);
return this;
```

Here there is no need for `else` since `if` returns.

- The `dayOfWeek()` method looks odd.  Why convert Sunday to Monday in all cases?
- `toJSDate()` seems like an odd name for a function. The word "to" tends to connote cases where some casting or data transformation might take place.  Here you are just returning the underlying date Object. Maybe just `getDateObj()` or something more descriptive of what is happening. Of course, the caller can always just access the `.date` property of the object to get the same result.
- I think some of the logic you are applying to try force you week to start on a certain day, might best be something you want to specify in configuration on instantiation, or via more appropriate specificity around methods that deal with work week constructs. Just totally re-mapping the days returned by underlying `Date` object seems to sort of hide this away from the caller.
- I think that perhaps you might need to look at the time component here as well.  To me, if I am trying to get the beginning of a week or month, I would be expecting to get 00:00:00 as the time component. On the other hand, if maybe the methods were named something like `modifyToBeginningOfMonth()` perhaps the current behavior would be more expected.
- Consider passing the `Date` object dependency in the constructor.  Right now you limit this class to only working with Date object for current timestamp.  If you took a `Date` object as parameter, you could set this `Date` object on your `HumanDate` object as is currently done, but allow the caller to fully utilize the capabilities of `Date` to set the timestamp to whatever they want to start with.  This also makes the dependency of this class really clear.
- You might give consideration to defining this class more as an extension of the underlying `Date` class.  That way you can eliminate needing to wrap underlying date properties and methods.

Comment: my fist version was an extension to the `Date.prototype` but then I thoungt mhmm let's wrap it... I don't convert Sunday but Sunday 0 to 7, to me it's the 7th day of week, it's odd when it's the 0th - I cannot think this way :] the same with the month, the first the is the 0th but a day of month starts with a 0 - it's a total mindfuck with the dates in javascript - the idea was to not having to read the docs everytime I have to do something with the date. -  I also think I should change the `day(-1)` to `addDays(-1)` or something like this.

Comment: @t3chb0t extending the Date prototype is perhaps compelling for your use case, but certainly is not something to take lightly, as Date is not a true object in a javascript sense, so you in essence have to instantiate it and then transform it to a HumanDate object, which is a little unusual.  Regarding zero-based dates.  It is common through many languages, so just something I would encourage you to embrace rather than making these transformations just for your "readability".  You are introducing unnecessary complexity in doing that.

Comment: @t3chb0t Also, your `dayOfWeek` function, does not do what you think it does.  It is only changing 0 to 1, not adding 1 to the underlying day of week value by 1 in all cases.

Comment: ...and of course day is a day of week, but day of month is date :-| I've never seen such a mess before ;-]

Comment: thx, then I have a bug there that I haven't found yet :-(

Comment: @t3chb0t I am no big fan of the javascript Date class implementation. It leaves a lot to be desired (especially plain-language types of operations like what you are shooting for.)

Comment: @t3chb0t A great example of a bug introduced due to unnecessary coding complexity :)  One thing I have found in working across different languages, is you often have to work with them the way they are set up to work, instead of exactly how you would like them to work.

Comment: me neither since the last few day but because I need to create some date-based filters for the sheets I have no other choice but to make it somehow understandable or rather more _natural_ ;-]

Comment: I prefer when everything about a date starts with the 1, this is consistent (also with my thinking) - they are not arrays so there should be no zeros.

Comment: I read the js documentation about the Date and I see it has a method `valueOf` that returns the private value of the date object - I think I shoud call the `toJSDate` the same.